# MySQL Join and Distinct

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two tables one called area and one called area covered.
Table area contains the fields postcode and region.

e.g:

area table contains **postcode** - AB10 **region** - Aberdeen

area covered table contains **id** - 1 **postcode** - AB10 **date** - 1364989057

Now I have a form which searches for either the postcode or the region. I'm using JQuery's autocomplete and can get either postcode or the region but not both.

at the moment I have:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT `postcode` FROM `areaCovered` WHERE `postcode` LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY `postcode` ASC") or die('Something went wrong');
```

Then I use the data retrieved from the database result and put into JSON:

```
$json = '[';
$first = true;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
    $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['postcode'].'"}';
}
$json .= ']';
echo $json;
```

How can I firstly join the two tables to search for either postcode or region that exists only in the area covered table and then output the result whether it is region or the postcode.

I hope that makes sense to you,

thanks

Comment: Are you sure `SELECT DISTINCT FROM ...` is working? It may need a field.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to add that it's `SELECT DISTINCT postcode FROM`

Comment: You can first retrieve the rows from **area** table with matching 'region' and union it with second table **areacovered** with matching 'postcode',so final query would contain complete set of all rows with either region matched or postcode matched .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `distinct` you should use `group by`, and join them.

Something in the lines of:

```
select
    a.`postcode` as postcode,
    a.`region` as region,
from
    `area` as a
    inner join
        `areaCovered` as ac
    on
        a.`postcode`=ac.`postcode`
where
    a.`postcode` like '%$search%'
    or
    a.`region` like '%$search%'
group by
    a.`postcode`
order by
    a.`postcode` asc
```

Preferably I would just `json_encode()` the whole result set and parse it client side, but it looks like you may need to have a special JSON structure for a jQuery plugin?

```
$list = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push(
        $list,
        array('value' => $row['postcode'] . ', ' . $row['region'])
    );
}

echo json_encode($list);
```

This will create a JSON structure that looks like;

```
[
    {
        "value": "123 45, Region 1"
    },
    {
        "value": "678 90, Region 2"
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. So for the JSON part, would I just put an if statement inside the loop checking for number of rows returned for either region or postcode?

Comment: @JackWillmor - Sorry, missed that -- adding it. I would return both and show them to the user.

Comment: I'm still having problems getting the results to fetch in to the autocomplete. What would the JSON look like?

Comment: If I run an error check, it comes up with the following message: `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `area` AS a INNER JOIN `areaCovered` AS bc ON a.`postcode` = bc.`postcode` ' at line 1`